# Removing columns with brackets in R doesn't work

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
ID    user    study    var   varb   varc   varf
101   a       b         3     4      3       4
102   b       a         4     5      5       6
103   g       a         4     4      5       6
104   b       c         6     7      7       5
```

I am trying to remove the first three columns by using the index positions

```
df <- df[-c(1:3)]
```

I was sure this method worked to remove columns. In fact, the first time I ran this line it did work as expected but now all it does is remove the rows instead of columns. Now, I'm just using the `subset()` method to remove columns which works fine. But, I want to brush up on my R since I have gotten rusty after not writing in it for so long. Where did I go wrong with the original method I was using before?

Comment: What does `class(df)` return? But `df[, -c(1:3)]` would probably work.

Comment: It returns two actually: data.table and data.frame

Comment: See the first bullet in [`data.table` FAQ 2.17 What are the smaller syntax differences between `data.frame` and `data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#SmallerDiffs)

Answer (score 3):

If it is a `data.table`, we may need

```
df[, -c(1:3), with = FALSE]
```

Or perhaps use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(-(1:3))
```

Comment: I think you are right. ```class(df)``` returns two classes of ```data.table``` and ```data.frame``` but I think it is acting as the former. Running the first method does what I wanted. I think it was an issue of the class. I just went with the first method I remembered and didn't even think to check.

Comment: @AcidCatfish you can have multiple attributes for class i.e. data.table is built on top of data.frame which will have some properties of data.frame with modified properties from data.table.  It is the first class, that is the prominent

Comment: ,@ akrun: Will this work?   `data.frame(df[-c(1:3)])`

Comment: @TarJae, I think the `data.frame` call should be `as.data.frame(df)[-(1:3)]` because your subsetting is done within the `data.table` and not after converting to `data.frame`

Comment: From `data.table v1.9.8`, you don’t need to use `with=FALSE`